# BeautifulSoup find all occurrences of specific text

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I will be analyzing a lot of sites with different htmls and I am trying to find all lines that contain specific text(inside html) using BeautifulSoup.

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")               
for text in soup.find_all():
    if "price" in text:
        print text
```

This approach doesn't work(even though "price" is mentioned over 40x in html). Maybe there is even better approach to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `BeautifulSoup`? It seems like if you just want the lines containing price it may be easier to look directly in the response data.  What's the end goal?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't let `BeautifulSoup` find you the nodes containing the desired text:

```
for node in soup.find_all(text=lambda x: x and "price" in x):
    print(node)
```

Comment: Like the idea but code above doesn't work, I changed print (py 2.7) am I forgetting anything else :) ? cheers

Answer (score 2):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:contains` pseudo class with * to consider all elements. Obviously some repeats as parents may contain children with same text. Here I search for `price`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.visitsealife.com/brighton/tickets/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.select('*:contains(price)')
print(items)
print(len(items))
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract all text from a given URL, you could just use something like:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")               

for element in soup.findAll(['script', 'style']):
    element.extract()

text = soup.get_text()
```

This will also remove possibly unwanted text inside `script` and `style` sections. You could then search for your required text using that.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use Beautiful soup to find the specific text in the html instead you can use the request for that For ex:

```
r = requests.get(url)
if 'specific text' in r.content:
    print r.content
```